# can someone help me to resolve this issue with R programming?

Tags: mysql, sql, r, google-analytics

I'm working on a table with employeeID, jobtitile and salery columns. I'm trying to query same results in SQL as well as in R but facing some difficulty.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, jobtitle,AVG(Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY jobtitle)
FROM EmployeeSalary
```

This query is shwoing correct result.When I'm executing the same query in R with the code:

```
employee_data %>% 
  select(employeeid, jobtitle,salary) %>%
  group_by(jobtitle) %>% 
  summarise(mean(salary))
```

The output is only showing jobtitle and mean salery column. Even when I use employeeid in group_by clause instead of select. Its still not working

Comment: perhaps just change the last line to `mutate(mean(salary))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `mutate` instead of `summarise` here. `summarise` will only show the column from your `group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)
employee_data <- data.frame(employeeid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                            jobtitle = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'), 
                            salary = c(100, 200, 300, 250, 400, 400))
employee_data %>% 
  select(employeeid, jobtitle,salary) %>%
  group_by(jobtitle) %>% 
  mutate(avg_salary = mean(salary)) %>%
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   employeeid jobtitle salary avg_salary
#>        <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1          1 a           100        200
#> 2          2 a           200        200
#> 3          3 a           300        200
#> 4          4 b           250        325
#> 5          5 b           400        325
#> 6          6 c           400        400
```